# C# How to include a variable with value into the email body to be sent as an email

Tags: c#, mysql, email

I have an 'Auto Generate' random number method and the value is stored into a string. I need the variable's value to show inside the `mail.Body` property. 
This is the code I have to generate the random number :

```
String id = " ";
Random rnd = new Random();

for(int a = 0; a <8; a++){
    id += rnd.Next(0,9);
}
```

This is my mail Body:

```
string Body = "Your New Value is " + id ;
mail.Body = Body;
```

But the email that I received only contains "Your new value is" as `Body`, without the autogenerated value in it.

What can I do to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running this example? If you fix the compiler errors (add semicolon at line 1, change `{` to `}` on line 5) it just works as intended. Please show working code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Its not sufficient code snippet to look for error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this C#-Code

```
Random rnd = new Random();
System.Text.StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++)
{
    result.Append(rnd.Next(0,9)); 
}
mail.Body = string.Format("Your New Value is '{0}'", result.ToString());
```

Your code didn't work because of line `id += rnd.Next(0,9);`. You try to concat a int to a string there. 
It should work with this `id += rnd.Next(0,9).ToString();`
Please don't use the '+'operator or the '+='operator to concat strings. Use StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try `string.Format`

```
string Body = string.Format("Your New Value is {0}", id);
```

Also, are you sure `id` contains what you expect?

Calling `.ToString()` on your number generator might help:

```
String id = string.Empty;
Random rnd = new Random();

for(int a = 0; a <8; a++){
    id += rnd.Next(0,9).ToString(); {
```

Also, the += is appending the string each time... Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GenerateRandomNum
{
    private static string id = "";

    public static string RandomNum()
    { 

   Random rnd = new Random();

   for(int a = 0; a <8; a++)
      {
      id +=(string)rnd.Next(0,9); 
      }
   }
}

class TestRandom
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       string Body = "Your New Value is " + GenerateRandomNum.RandomNum();
       mail.Body = Body;

   }
}
```

Hope this will help you